# How to solve $100x +19 =0 \pmod{23}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How to solve $100x +19 =0 \pmod{23}$, which is $100x=-19 \pmod{23}$ ?
In general I want to know how to solve $ax=b \pmod{c}$.

Comment: Can anyone suggest the General solution for this type of equation

Comment: I'd say mandatory reading material here: [Modular multiplicative inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint** $\displaystyle\rm\,\ mod\ 23\!:\,\ x\,\equiv\, \frac{\color{brown}{-19}}{4\cdot \color{#0A0}{25}}
\,\equiv\,\frac{\color{brown}4}{4\cdot\color{#0A0} 2}
\,\equiv\, \frac{\color{blue}1}2
\,\equiv\, \frac{\color{blue}{24}}2
\,\equiv\, 12,\ \:$ 
by $\:\ \begin{array}{r}\color{brown}{{-}19\equiv 4}, & \color{blue}{1\equiv 24}\\ \color{#0A0}{25\equiv 2}\,\end{array} $

Answer (score 4):

First, $100=4\cdot 23+8$, so $100\equiv 8\pmod{23}$. Then
$$
100x\equiv 8x\equiv -19\equiv 4\pmod{23}.
$$
Since $4$ and $23$ are coprime, $4$ is invertible in $\mathbb{Z}/23\mathbb{Z}$, ($\mathbb{Z}/23\mathbb{Z}$ is in fact a field), so multiplying by $4^{-1}$ yields $2x\equiv 1\pmod{23}$. Multiply both sides by $12$ to get $24x\equiv 12\pmod{23}$. But $24\equiv 1\pmod{23}$, so $x\equiv 12\pmod{23}$.

For the general solution to $ax\equiv b\pmod{c}$, it is a common theorem that $ax\equiv b\pmod{c}$ has a solution iff $d\mid b$ where $d=\gcd(a,c)$. When this is the case, the solutions form an arithmetic progression with common difference $c/d$, for a total of $d$ solutions modulo $c$. You can read about this for instance as Theorem 2.17, page 62, of Ivan Niven's *Introduction to the Theory of Numbers* in the Section "Solutions to Congruences."

Answer (score 3):

$$ x \equiv \frac{-19}{100} \equiv \frac{4}{100} \equiv \frac{1}{25} \equiv \frac{1}{2} \equiv \frac{ 12}{24} \equiv 12.$$

Comment: How did you get from (-19/100) to (4/100)
and from (1/25 ) to (1/2) ???

Comment: @Khaled In mod 23, adding or subtracting multiples of 23 makes no difference to the value. So I added 23 to -19 to get 4, and subtracted 23 from 25 to get 2.

Answer (score 2):

A [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183900/what-are-the-methods-of-solving-linear-congruences/183923#183923). First step we simplify the congruence as
$$ 100 x \equiv -19({\rm mod}\, 23) \Rightarrow  8 x \equiv 4 ({\rm mod}\, 23) \,. $$
The last congruence follows from subtracting multiples of $23$ from 100 and adding $23$ to $-19$ which is allowed by the rules of congruences. We can simplify the last congruence further to

$$ 2 x \equiv 1 ({\rm mod}\, 23 ) \,.$$

since $ {\rm gcd}(4,23) = 1 \,.$

Now, since ${\rm gcd}( 2,23 )=1 \,, $ then the congruence has exactly one solution (this is a theorem) and by inspection you can see that $x=12$ is a solution.

**Another Approach**

This is a technique can be used to solve linear congruences.,

if $ a x \equiv b({\rm mod}\, m) $, then you can reduce it to $ m y \equiv -b({\rm mod}\, a)\,.$ If $y_0$ is a solution for of the reduced congruence, then $x_0$ defined by 
$$ x_0 = \frac{my_0+b}{a} \,.$$
is a solution of the original congruence.

Applying this algorithm to your problem, we can reduce our congruence to

$$ 23 y \equiv 19({\rm mod}\, 8) \Rightarrow 7 y \equiv 3({\rm mod}\, 8)\,. $$
You can see now by inspection that $y_0 = 5 $ is a solution of the last congruence. Substituting in 
$$  x_0 = \frac{m y_0 + b}{a} = \frac{23.5-19 - 19}{8}= 12\,. $$

Note that, you can repeat the same algorithm to the last congruence which results in a simpler congruence. If we do so, we get the following congruence
$$ z \equiv -3({\rm mod}\, 7) \,$$
such that 
$$ y_0 = \frac{m z_0 + b}{a} \,. $$ 
We can see by inspection that $z_0=4$ is a solution which implies

$$ y_0= \frac{8.4+3}{7} = 5 \,$$

which what we got before.

Answer (score 1):

$100x +19 =0 \pmod{23}$

$100x  ≡ -19 \pmod{23}$

$92x+8x=4-23\pmod{23}$

$=>8x≡4 \pmod{23}$ dividing both sides by $23$ and taking resdiues,

So,  $2x≡1 \pmod{23}$  dividing both sides by $4$ which is possible as $(4,23)=1,$

Now $\frac{23}{2}=11+\frac{1}{2}$  So, $23-2\cdot 11=1$

(Please refer to [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ContinuedFractionFundamentalRecurrenceRelation.html)  and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Theorem_3), for the theorem used.)

So, $2x≡23-2\cdot 11 \pmod{23}=>2x≡-22\pmod{23}$

$x≡-11\pmod{23}$ dividing both sides by $2$ as $(2,23)=1$

$x≡-11\pmod{23}≡12\pmod{23}$

To solve the general problem, $ax≡b\pmod{c}$,

$d=(a,b)$ must divide $c$ to admit any solution(according to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruence_theorem) or [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LinearCongruenceEquation.html)).

If we divide either side by $d$, so that $Ax≡B\pmod{C}$  where $\frac{a}{A}=\frac{b}{B}=\frac{c}{C}=d$ and (A,B)=1.

Using convergent property of continued fraction, we can get integers $r,s$ such that $rA-sB=±1$

For example, $\frac{17}{13}=1+\frac{4}{13}=1+\frac{1}{\frac{13}{4}}=1+\frac{1}{3+\frac{1}{4}}$

So, the convergent here is $1+\frac{1}{3}=\frac{4}{3}$

So. $17\cdot 3 -  13\cdot 4$ must be $±1$ , and is $-1$.

Put $rA-sB$ with proper sign in place of $(1)$,  $Ax≡B(1)\pmod{C}$

One example can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186881/what-is-the-best-way-to-solve-a-problem-given-remainders-and-divisors/186983#186983).

Please refer to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruence_theorem#Solving_a_linear_congruence) for the details.

Comment: can you explain =>8x≡4(mod23) dividing both sides by 23,

Comment: @RahulTaneja, could you please check the modified answer.

Comment: got your point. Thanks
can you answer the second part of this question i.e. general solution