# how to find multiplicative inverse in a Galois field?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, galois-theory, inverse

How to find the multiplicative inverse of $$x^2+1 \pmod{x^4+x+1}$$

Comment: Compute the Bezout factors $a(x)(x^2+1)+b(x)(x^4+x+1)=1$ using Euclid's algorithm. Then the class of $a(x)$ is the inverse of $x^2+1$

Comment: @Shubham, this is not meant to be a homework answer site, per se - we are happy to help, but please give context, or show what you tried and/or what you don't understand.

Comment: A good start to get further help (and insight) would be to edit your question as to show us the gcd of $x^2+1$ and $x^4+x+1$, which you can compute using Euclid's algorithm. If you don't manage this, explain where you're stuck.

Comment: Sorry, @peterag I was not asking it for my homework. I studied Galois field and was unable to calculate the multiplicative inverse. I want to know the approach not the solution

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: What is the prime field here? If $\Bbb{F}_2$ aka $GF(2)$, then you can look it up from [a table of discrete logarithms](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/591254/11619) I prepared for referrals like this. $x^2+1\equiv x^8$, so its inverse is $$x^7\equiv x^3+x+1.$$ Without telling the prime field, you leave us guessing.

Answer (score 1):

If the field has characteristic 5 things change. This is over the rationals.

$$  \left(   x^{4}  +  x  + 1 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{2}  + 1 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{4}  +  x  + 1 \right)  =  \left(   x^{2}  + 1 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{2}  - 1 \right) } +  \left(   x  + 2 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{2}  + 1 \right)  =  \left(   x  + 2 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x  - 2 \right) } +  \left( 5  \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   x  + 2 \right)  =  \left( 5  \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  x  + 2 }{ 5 }  \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 0}{1} $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 1}{0} $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{2}  - 1 \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   x^{2}  - 1 \right) }{ \left( 1  \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   x  - 2 \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   x^{3}  - 2 x^{2}  -  x  + 3 \right) }{ \left(   x  - 2 \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  x  + 2 }{ 5 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{  x^{4}  +  x  + 1 }{ 5 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{  x^{2}  + 1 }{ 5 }  \right) } $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{4}  +  x  + 1 \right)  \left(   \frac{  x  - 2 }{ 5 }  \right)  -  \left(   x^{2}  + 1 \right)  \left(   \frac{  x^{3}  - 2 x^{2}  -  x  + 3 }{ 5 }  \right)  =  \left( -1  \right)  $$

Answer (score 1):

All the fancy methods are  fine, but here’s a back-alley way of doing it, strongly dependent on which field $\Bbb F$ your coefficients come from:

In the case the constants are from the field with two elements, then the field in which $x^2+1$ sits has $16=2^4$ elements, and its multiplicative group is cyclic of order $15$. This means that any nonzero element of the big field, say $z$, satisfies the condition that $z^{15}=1$, and consequently $z^{-1}=z^{14}$, which is easily calculated as $[((z^2)\cdot z)^2\cdot z]^2$, which you can do with only five multiplications in your field.

Answer (score 0):

*Easy* by [Inverse Reciprocity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/326608/242):  $ $  first compute $\,\color{#0a0}{\large \frac{1}f} \,\bmod\, x^2\!+1,\,$  for $\, f = x^4\!+\!x\!+\!1,\,$ i.e.

$\!\!\bmod x^2\!+1\!:\ x\equiv i\,\Rightarrow\,\color{#0a0}{\dfrac{1}f}\equiv \dfrac{1}{i^4\!+\!i\!+\!1}\equiv \dfrac{1}{2+i}\equiv \color{#0a0}{\dfrac{2-i}5}\,$ by *rationalizing* denom

therefore  $\ \color{#0a0}{\frac{1}5(2\!-\!x)}\, f = 1 + (x^2\!+\!1)\,\color{#c00}g,\ $ so

$\!\!\bmod f\!:\,\ \dfrac{1}{x^2\!+1}\equiv -\color{#c00}g\equiv \dfrac{1-\frac{1}5 (2\!-\!x) f}{x^2\!+1} \equiv {\large \frac{1}5}(x^3\!-2x^2\!-x+3)$

Comment: Note: the quotient can be calculated very quickly *mentally* as below

$$-5\color{#c00}g = \dfrac{(x\!-\!2)f+5}{x^2+1} = \dfrac{(x\!-\!2)(\color{#0a0}{x^4\!-\!1}+x\!+\!2)+5}{\color{#0a0}{x^2+1}} = (x\!-\!2)(\color{#0a0}{x^2\!-\!1})+1\qquad\qquad$$

Comment: Inverse reciprocity is a special case of the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3140261/242). $\ \ $