# How to compute inverses in $\mathbb{Q}[x] / \langle x^3 + 3x + 3 \rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, euclidean-algorithm

When working in the field $\mathbb{Q}[X] / \langle X^3 + 3X + 3 \rangle$, let $a$ represent the image of $X$ under the natural quotient mapping.

I am trying to understand the range of strategies that I might use to represent the element $\frac{1}{a^2 +1}$ in the form $k_2 a^2 + k_1 a + k_0$ with $k_i \in \mathbb{Q}$.
I have already determined the following:

1. $\frac{1}{a}$ is $-\frac{1}{3} a^2 - 1$, an answer which I found by rearranging the equation $a^3 + 3a + 3 = 0$.
2. $\frac{1}{a+1}$ is $a^2 - a + 4$, which was found by dividing $a^3 + 3a + 4$ by $a+1$.

In order to find $\frac{1}{a^2 + 1}$, I am attempting to use the same method. I started by rearranging $a^3 + 3a + 3 = 0$ to form the equation $\frac{1}{a^2 + 1} = \frac {a}{-2a-3}$ and proceeding with more division.

I have checked my work with Sage. The correct representation is $\frac{2}{13}a^2 - \frac{3}{13}a + \frac{4}{13}$, but the correct path forward is eluding me at the moment. Any possible strategy hints would be welcome. Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: I would apply the Euclidean algorithm to the polynomials $x^2+1$ and $x^3+3x+3$.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3140261/242) in the dupe for how to very simply compute the inverse via the (forward) extended Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: **Or** as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3465998) we can use **inverse reciprocity**, to reduce to computing an inverse in $\Bbb Q[x]/(x^2+1)\cong\Bbb Q[i]$ by $\rm\color{#0a0}{rationalizing}$ denominators. Write the Bezout equation as
$\tag*{}$
$\qquad\qquad 1 = ag + bf = a(x^3+3x+3) + b(x^2+1)$
$\tag*{}$
$\!\bmod\, f\!=\!\color{#c00}{x^2}+1\!:\,\ a\equiv  \dfrac{1}{g}\equiv \dfrac{1}{3+3x+x\color{#c00}{x^2}}\equiv \dfrac{1}{3+2x}\equiv \dfrac{3-2x}{\color{#0a0}{13}},\ $ so
$\tag*{}$
$\!\bmod g\!:\ \dfrac{1}f \equiv b\equiv \dfrac{1-ag}f\equiv \dfrac{2x^2-3x+4}{13}\ \ $

Comment: See also [quotient reciprocity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1214494/bbbzi-langle-2-rangle-cong-bbbzx-langle-x21-2-rangle-cong-bbb/1214702#1214702) $\ \ $

Comment: We can continue your inverse calculation from $\,\color{#c00}{b\equiv x/(-2x-3)}\,$ as below

$$\begin{align}
[\![1]\!]\quad\ \ \ (x^2+1)\, b&\,\equiv\, 1\\
[\![2]\!]\quad  \color{#c00}{{-}(2x+3)\,b} &\,\equiv\ \color{#c00}x\\
(2x\!-\!3)\:\![\![2]\!]+4\!\:[\![1]\!]\qquad\qquad\  13\,b &\,\equiv\,  (2x\!-\!3)x+4 \end{align}\quad$$

It's the forward extended Euclidean algorithm [presented](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3140261/242) in the first dupe, but we omitted one column.

Comment: The prior calculation can be expressed naturally in *fractional* form, e.g. see the 2nd section  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4698767/242), which is a polynomial analog of the [integer case](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/25395/242). $\ \ $