# How to solve linear congruences as a newbie?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

**Please, before referring to another problem on the site or giving a link, I would like to say I read most of them such as: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186674/how-to-solve-100x-19-0-pmod23), [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183900/what-are-the-methods-of-solving-linear-congruences), [and many others](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456690/find-a-solution-of-9x-24-mod-21) but due to the (subtle) difference in my question, I'm having a really hard time to apply the methods used in other questions.**

We yesterday had our first lecture about Number Theory. I have been trying to work on this problem since yesterday evening.

$$16a + 17b + 18c \equiv 19\pmod{100}$$
It's given that $ 1 \leq a,b,c \leq 99$ and that $a = 95\ and\ c=11$. We want to know what $b$ is.

I know that the answer is $53$ ( I used the naive way to get the answer) but I fail to do it according to the official methods. Can someone please explain this?

I tried this: ( i filled both **a** and **c** in)

$1718 +17b \equiv 19\ (mod\ 100)$

$17b \equiv 19-1718\ (mod\ 100)$

$17b \equiv -1699\ (mod\ 100)$

$$ x \equiv \frac{-1699}{17} \equiv \frac{-1699}{17} \equiv \frac{1}{17}\ i\ got\ stuck\ here$$

I also tried to work with it simplified:
$$17b \equiv 1 (mod\ 100)$$ I thought i was almost done here since i was able to write it like this: 
$$b \equiv \dfrac{1}{17} (mod\ 100)$$
So i thought there is some $b$ number if i divide it by a $1/17$ i get $n$ as an answer and $100$ as rest but even doing so yielded in a wrong answer. Can someone please help?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25390/how-to-find-the-inverse-modulo-m

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I just applied the extended Euclidean algorithm such that $1s+100t = 1$ where t,s are integers. I found s = -99 , t =1. So that $1b \equiv 1 \pmod {100}$ but it was wrong for some reason

Comment: I don't think there are special ways for newbies, and no official ways. The (extended) Euclidean algorithm is just the most handy tool.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Could you please show me how The (extended) Euclidean algorithm will apply here. I tried and failed as i commented above

Comment: Sure. [Extended Euclidean algorithm](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ExtendedGCD%5B17,100%5D) will give you the result $\{1, \{-47, 8\}\}$, meaning the GCD is $1$, and $(-47)\cdot17+8\cdot100=1$. And that means $1/17=-47=53\pmod {100}$.

Comment: @ProfessorVector I finally understand how the algorithm works and i was able to understand everything you did till " And that means ". May i ask how did you conclude that?

Answer (score 1):

HINT.-**As a newbie** you could act as follows:

First at all, note that $17$ is invertible modulo $100$ because it is not divisible by $2$ nor by $5$ so $17b \equiv 1 (mod\ 100)$ has solution.

Since $17n=17+17\cdots+17$ (n times), you could add successively $17$  plus $17$ until you get a number of the form $100x+1$ (this requires to be some patient having into account you know the answer is $53$).

Another shorter way is to add successively $100$ adding $1$ and dividing by $17$ until you have an exact quotient which is precisely your answer.This way requires just $9$ times instead of $53$.