# Solution of $19 x \equiv 1 \pmod{35}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

$19 x \equiv 1 \pmod{35}$

For this, may I know how to get the smallest value of $x$. I know that there is a theorem like $19^{34} = 1 \pmod {35}$. But I don't think it is the smallest.

Comment: See [What are the methods of solving linear congruences?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183900/what-are-the-methods-of-solving-linear-congruences) or [How to find solutions of linear Diophantine ax + by = c?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20717/how-to-find-solutions-of-linear-diophantine-ax-by-c/) Extended Euclidean algorithm is often useful, see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85830/how-to-use-the-extended-euclidean-algorithm-manually).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, $\gcd(19,35)=1\implies \exists x_0,y_0\in \Bbb Z$ such that $19x_0+35y_0=1$.

You can apply euclid's algorithm, $$35=1\cdot19+16$$ $$19=1\cdot16+3$$ $$16=5\cdot3+1$$ $$\implies 1=16-5\cdot3=16-(19-1\cdot16)5=(35-19)-5(19-(35-19))=6\cdot35-11\cdot19$$ $$\implies19\cdot11=35\cdot6-1\implies 19\cdot(-11)\equiv 1\pmod {35}\implies 19\cdot24\equiv 1\pmod {35}$$

Comment: I don't think it is correct
19.11≡34(mod35)

Comment: @Avatar, Should it be $-11$?:)

Comment: @jun: Thanks for pointing out the error.I updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Your question can be stated like this: What is the inverse of $19$ modulo $35$?

Since $\gcd(19,35) = 1$, $19$ is invertible mod $35$. Hence there is a unique solution $x\in\{0,\ldots,34\}$ of your equation. How to find it?

**Method 1:** You could just check all these possibilities to find it.

**Method 2:** A more structured (and in general, more efficient) way is to use the [extended Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) on the pair $(35,19)$. It gives you numbers $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $19a + 35b = 1$. Now reading this equation modulo $35$, $$19a\equiv 1\mod 35.$$

**Method 3:** As you wrote, by Fermat $19^{34}\equiv 1\mod 35$, so $19\cdot 19^{33} \equiv 1\mod 35$. Now you can evaluate $19^{33}$ by the [square-and-multiply](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) algorithm. However note that in general, this is slower than the extended Euclid algorithm.

Concerning your question on the smallest $x$: The solution set has the structure $x_0 + 35\mathbb{Z}$. So if you have *any* solution $x_0$, the smallest solution is the remainder of $x_0$ modulo $35$.

Comment: thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score 3):

Besides Euclides's Algorithm you can try other, sometimes quicker, methods. The following is done modulo $\,35\,$:

$$19\cdot2 =38=3\;,\;\;3\cdot 12=36=1\Longrightarrow1=3\cdot 12=19\cdot 2\cdot 12=19\cdot 24=1\Longrightarrow$$

$$\Longrightarrow 24=19^{-1}\Longrightarrow x=24$$

The "trick" above is to find some multiple of $\,19\,$ (namely, $\,3=19\cdot 2\,$) which is reasonably close to a multiple of $\,35\,$ (and thus its residue modulo $\,35\,$ is reasonable "small") and then work with that residue as it shall be easier to find its multiplicative inverse.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\rm\,\ mod\ 35\!:\,\ 19x\equiv 1\iff x\equiv \dfrac{1}{19}\equiv \dfrac{2}{38}\equiv \dfrac{2}3\equiv \dfrac{24}{36}\equiv\dfrac{24}1$

**Remark** $\ $ We used [Gauss's algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/130934/23500) for computing inverses $\rm\:mod\ p\:$ prime.

**Beware** $\ $ One can employ fractions $\rm\ x\equiv b/a\ $ in modular arithmetic (as above) only when the fractions have denominator $ $ *coprime* $ $ to the modulus $ $ (else the fraction may not *uniquely exist,* $ $  i.e. the equation $\rm\: ax\equiv b\,\ (mod\ m)\:$ might have no solutions, or more than one solution). The reason why such fraction arithmetic works here (and in analogous contexts) will become clearer when one learns about the *universal* properties of fraction rings (*localizations*).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is of the form $$ax\equiv\mod n.$$ If $\gcd(a,n)=1$, then the unique  solution is given by
$$x\equiv x_0\mod n$$ where $x_0$ is a particular solution of the given linear congruence. You may refer [here](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Solution_of_Linear_Congruence). Note that $\gcd(19,35)=1.$ One such particular solution of $$19x\equiv 1\mod 35$$ is given $x_0=-11.$ Note that $-11\equiv 24\mod 35.$ The unique solution is given by$$x\equiv 24\mod 35.$$