# Solving Linear Congruence Equation: Finding the Nonnegative Integer Representation

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I have a question for a part of the following problem: `Solve the linear congruence 7x ≡ 6(mod 29)`

I understand how to find the linear combination equality using the extended Euclidean Algorithm, which is this: `1 = 1⋅29 − 4⋅7`

But what is throwing me is that I can't find a way to find the nonnegative integer representation less than 29 of the inverse of `7`. I know by my equation that `-4` is the inverse of 7, but how would I go about this?

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183900/what-are-the-methods-of-solving-linear-congruences/183923#183923).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is written down explicitly in your post. You wrote that using the Extended Euclidean Algorithm, you reached $1=1\cdot 29-4\cdot 7$. This *says* that $-4$ is the inverse of $7$. If you want positive, use $29+(-4)$.

Comment: Thanks. That was painfully obvious...

Answer (score 1):

Multiply $7x\equiv 6$ by $-4$ on both sides to get $x\equiv -24\equiv 5$.

Sorry, misread the question.  $-4\equiv 25\pmod{29}$, so $25$ is the least positive representation of $-4$.