# Proving that a set Rn (relatively prime with respect to any n) is a group

Tags: cryptography

Question: prove that the set of all Rn (relatively prime with respect to any n) is a group

... there is a theorem that states Rn is a group for n > 0, but i dont know where that came from...

(Just to be clear, for example, the set of all Rn and n = 15 is {1,2,4,7,8,11,13,14}).

i found out the definition of a group. a set A, with an operation * is a group if:

- CLOSURE: For all a, b in A, the result of the operation a * b is also in A.
- ASSOCIATIVITY: For all a, b and c in A, the equation (a * b) * c = a * (b * c) holds.
- IDENTITY ELEMENT: There exists an element e in A, such that for all elements a in A, the equation e * a = a * e = a holds.
- INVERSE ELEMENT: For each a in A, there exists an element b in A such that a * b = b * a = e, where e is the identity element.

What I have done so far: I was able to prove the "identity element" part. since all the elements in Rn are less than n, and 1 is always in Rn for any integer n > 0 (because 1 is relatively prime to any integer n >= 1)... and any element in the set of Rn multiplied by 1 will cause no changes, thus the equation e * a = a * e = a, where e = 1, holds and proves the identity element part...

but im having trouble trying to prove the other properties... i have an idea that for multiplying 2 or more numbers, associativity always holds, but im not sure if that proof is enough? am i even in the right track?

Comment: whoops! sorry. thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said what the multiplication is.  Conventionally in this context one reduces modulo $n$; thus if $n=15$ and one multiplies $11$ by $13$, one gets the remainder on division of $1\times13=143$ by $15$, and this is $8$, since $143=15\times 9 + 8$.  If you're convinced that a number cannot have more than one prime factorization, then you conclude that when you multiply two numbers that have no prime factors in common with $15$, you get a product that has no prime factors in common with $15$.  The set of all common factors of $15$ and $x$ is the same as the set of all common factors of $15$ and the remainder on division of $x$ by $15$ (that's a routine algebra exercise). Thus the only common factor between $15$ and the remainder is $1$, so you've got a number in the set of those less than $15$ that are coprime to $15$.  That proves closure.

You're on the right track with associativity.

As for inverses, that's more involved.  See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67171/calculating-the-modular-multiplicative-inverse-without-all-those-strange-looking).  (That question assumes the modulus is prime, so not everything is *exactly* the same.)

Comment: thanks! your answer in the closure part helped a lot! still having trouble with the inverse though, haha!

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add an alternate proof, which basically involves proving that each element of the set maps to a different element, under multiplication mod n.

For this, we show two things (associativity already follows from the associativity of multiplication):

(a.) If $a, b \in \mathbb{U}_n \implies ab \in \mathbb{U}_n$. This follows since if $a$ and $b$ have no common divisors with $n$, then $ab$ can't have a common divisor either, because if $ab$ has a common divisor, then it has atleast one common prime divisor $p | ab, p| n$. Thus, either $p | a$ or $p | b$, which means that either $a$ or $b$ has a common divisor $p$ with n, which is a contradiction.

(b.) $a, b, c \in \mathbb{U}_n \implies a\cdot c \ne a\cdot b \;\;\text{if}\;\; b \ne c$. This follows because if
$$a\cdot b = a\cdot c \implies a\cdot b \equiv a\cdot c\mod{n} \implies  n \mid ab - ac$$
$\implies n | a(b - c) \implies n | b - c,$ since $gcd(a, n) = 1$

Since $b, c < n \;\;\text{and}\;\;b \ne c$, this is not possible, and so, $a\cdot b \ne a\cdot c$.

Thus, each element in the set $\mathbb{U}_n$ maps to a unique element under mult. mod n, and hence there is some element that maps to 1, since $1 \in \mathbb{U}_n$. So, there exists an inverse of each of the elements in $\mathbb{U}_n$. This also proves that $\mathbb{U}_n$ is a group under multiplication mod n.